# Optimize this Query in Unity catalog in databricks

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

I have below code which works fine and it is used to create groups and views in a Databricks workspace after checking if its already exists or not. I would like to further optimize this query. Does anyone has any suggesstion on that as how can I optimize this code. Remember I am using unity Catalog in Databricks so not all attributes from pyspark sql is supported there:

```
target_database = "main.deltalake_db"
distinctprojects = spark.sql("SELECT DISTINCT requestProjectUrlName FROM main.deltalake_db.Customers_Log_Table_test")

for project in distinctprojects.collect():
    project_name = project['requestProjectUrlName']
    view_name = f"view_{project_name.replace(' ', '_').replace('-', '_')}"
    groupname = f"users_{view_name}"
    
    # Check if group already exists
    group_exists = False
    for group in spark.sql("SHOW GROUPS").collect():
        if 'name' in group:
            group_name = group['name']
        else:
            group_name = group['groupName']
        if group_name == groupname:
            group_exists = True
            print(f"Group {groupname} already exists.")
            break
    
    if not group_exists:
        create_group = f"""
        CREATE GROUP {groupname} with USER `xyz@test.com`
        """
        try: 
            spark.sql(create_group)            
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error creating group {groupname}: {e}")
        else:
            print(f"Group {groupname} created successfully.")
    
    # Check if view already exists
    view_exists = False
    for table in spark.catalog.listTables(target_database):
        if table.name == view_name:
            view_exists = True
            print(f"View {view_name} already exists.")
            break
    
    if not view_exists:
        create_view_query = f"""
        CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW {target_database}.{view_name} AS
        SELECT * FROM {target_database}.Customers_Log_Table
        WHERE 
          CASE
            WHEN is_member('{groupname}') AND requestProjectUrlName = '{project_name}' THEN TRUE 
            ELSE FALSE
      END;
    """ 
    try: 
        spark.sql(create_view_query)
        
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error creating view {view_name}: {e}")
    else:
        print(f"View {view_name} created successfully.")
```

Comment: can you describe what this query should do...

Comment: yes its basically creating views on the table based on one column. and corresponding to each view I am creating user groups. also making sure only those corresponding groups has access to their corresponding views